# Show enum name value for corresponding Id in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, class, asp.net-core, enums

I am developing a web application and .NET Core and recently bumped against this issue.

It shows the Id of the enum value in: `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MutatieReden)` but I want to show the name for the enum as this is a 'Details' view.

My enum is built like this, am I missing something?:

```
//Class property
public Reden? MutatieReden { get; set; }

//Enum
    public enum Reden
    {
        [Display(Name = "Niet van toepassing")] NietVanToepassing = 1,
        [Display(Name = "Administratieve reden")] AdministratieveReden = 2,
        [Display(Name = "Niet akkoord klant")] NietAkkoordKlant = 3,
        [Display(Name = "Incasso blokkade")] IncassoBlokkade = 4,
    }
```

I tried various solutions but most of them were for regular ASP.NET MVC and answers were all outdated.

EDIT: This is not a duplicate as this is for ASP.NET Core and the other solutions are for .NET MVC 5.1. Tried these solutions already.

Comment: Show us two of the approaches you tried. In your question.

Comment: By "name" here, do you actually mean `"Niet van toepassing"` etc?

Comment: @MarcGravell yes, I want to show these values instead of the Id its giving me

Comment: @AidsJung , I tried to reproduce the issue with ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2 ,but the name of Display attribute showed well . [Here](https://microsoftapc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/v-xuelc_microsoft_com/EWBkn0TDA5BGoL1Qf18HLEgBAumDSFGhj7SEPZUj1kh4iQ?e=ddSEVv) is my test demo , you could check for the difference . If you could share the reproducible demo, it would help us provide effective suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need in `Display` attribute at all:

```
Reden enum_value = Reden.AdministratieveReden;
string enum_name = Enum.GetName(typeof(Reden), enum_value);
```

Comment: I benched this, and it's twice as slow as `enum_value.ToString()`.

Answer (score 4):

For display purpose, I think we can use:

```
@Html.Display(Model.MutatieReden.GetDisplayName())
```

Or you even can create extra properties for display only:

```
public string MutatieRedenText { get => this.MutatieReden.GetDisplayName(); }
```

Add this static method into a static class like **public static class EnumHelper**

```
public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum val)
    {
        return val.GetType()
                  .GetMember(val.ToString())
                  .FirstOrDefault()
                  ?.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>(false)
                  ?.Name
                  ?? val.ToString();
    }
```

PS: I haven't tested with compiler but it probably works

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.name?view=net-5.0) : _"Do not use this property to get the value of the Name property. Use the GetName method instead."_ However, that method will throw an exception if the attribute has not been set.